# PDF is not shown in java swt browser

Tags: java, pdf, swt, pdf-viewer

I'm using java swt browser for java single page application. In the browser the webpages is showing the PDF successfully, but in the swt browser PDFs are not shown properly.
I'm using `<object/>` tag to display the PDFs.

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input[type=button]', function(){
               var datas =  '<object data="files/Documents/'+$(this).attr('class')+'#page=1&zoom=130" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>';
              $('#custom-size-dialogBox').dialogBox({

                width: screen.width-100,
                height: screen.height-100,
                                hasMask: true,
                                title: 'View Details',
                hasClose: true,
                content: datas

                            });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume that a system-pdf viewer is installed, you can use the Browser widget by setting the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>

</head>
<body onResize="fit();">
<embed
    type="application/pdf"
    src="http://www.adobe.com/security/pdfs/riskcompliance_faq.pdf"
    id="pdfDocument">
</embed>    
<script type="text/javascript">
fit();
function fit() {
 var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
//Non-IE
myWidth = window.innerWidth;
myHeight = window.innerHeight;
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
//IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
//IE 4 compatible
myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}
document.getElementById('pdfDocument').width = myWidth;
document.getElementById('pdfDocument').height = myHeight;
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The src of the embed tag must point to the desired pdf, for local files: file://myPath/../test.pdf